# Unhandled Java exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException connecting to Sql Server from Linux Server usingJruby

Tags: sql-server, linux, jdbc, jruby, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server Database using jruby on Linux server.
This is how my code looks like:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'java'
require '/home/testuser/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar'
Java::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://myremotedb.test.com:19263;databaseName=testappdatabase'
connection = java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url, 'testuser1', 'testpass1')
testconn = conn.createstatement
```

When i do this, I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Java exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'CORP/infautomic'. ClientConnectionId:ef4f1526-86d3-4e31-a3a8-31c1b026ac4b
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'testuser1'. ClientConnectionId:ef4f1526-86d3-4e31-a3a8-31c1b026ac4b
              makeFromDatabaseError at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException.java:216
                              onEOF at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/tdsparser.java:254
                              parse at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/tdsparser.java:84
                          sendLogon at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:2908
                              logon at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:2234
                         access$000 at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:41
                          doExecute at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:2220
                            execute at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/IOBuffer.java:5696
                     executeCommand at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1715
                      connectHelper at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1326
                              login at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:991
                            connect at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:827
                            connect at com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java:1012
                      getConnection at java/sql/DriverManager.java:664
                      getConnection at java/sql/DriverManager.java:247
                             invoke at java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498
  invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:483
                 invokeStaticDirect at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:375
       invokeOther17:get_connection at sqljdbc.rb:7
                             <main> at sqljdbc.rb:7
                invokeWithArguments at java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.java:627
                          runScript at org/jruby/Ruby.java:827
                        runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:746
                        runNormally at org/jruby/Ruby.java:764
                        runFromMain at org/jruby/Ruby.java:577
                      doRunFromMain at org/jruby/Main.java:417
                        internalRun at org/jruby/Main.java:305
                                run at org/jruby/Main.java:232
                               main at org/jruby/Main.java:204
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: That exception message suggests that either the user doesn't exist or the password is incorrect.  Can you log in with those credentials using a different tool (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio)?

Comment: Hi Luke, I am able to login to that using other tool like(ruby tiny_tds gem). I am getting this error when  i use the JDBC Driver in JRuby.

Comment: OK, I've taken a closer look at your stacktrace and noticed that you haven't anonymised it completely.  You're actually trying to log in as `CORP/infautomic`, not `testuser1`.  Is `CORP` the domain the SQL Server database is on?  Are you trying to use Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication?

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Comment: Hi @andrea-lam-MSFT, My issue is fixed. Thanks for your help